# Wholesale Registration not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php, html

I created a wholesale registration form some time ago which when paired with Vinai_CustomerActivation module allowed anyone interested in a wholesale account to register and wait for their account to be activated... it worked perfectly for quite some time but all of a sudden whenever you fill in the wholesale registration form it is creating a general account..

I've got the following inside the  tag on the wholesale registration form

```
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" id="group_id" value="2"/>
```

Is there anything that could of caused that to be ignored? I tested it on multiple occasions and it worked but now for the last couple of days it doesn't work

I've also got this in the _`getCustomer` function in AccountController.php

```
  if($this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id'))
     { $customer->setGroupId($this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id'));
     } else {
    $customer->getGroupId(); } 

            return $customer;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by creating a new entry in the customer_form_attribute table with the form code = customer_account_create and attribute id = 10

Hope this helps someone